# How to write arduino code which reads the value of a flex sensor?

Tags: input

Since this is this the first time im doing Arduino, im really confused what the code is to:

write a code which reads the value(nae the value 'flexValue') of a flex sensor connected to analog input AN0.

The value should be a 10-bit integer number having value between 0-1023, inclusive.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogRead

Answer (score 1):

You should call the function `analogRead()`, and pass the value of `A0` into it because you want to read pin A0. For example:

```
flexVal = analogRead(A0);
```

The function `analogRead()` will return a value from 0-1023, just as you require.

When you call this function, the CPU configures the on-board ADC (analog-to-digital converter) to take a reading from pin A0. The ADC on the Arduino has 10-bit resolution, so it will return a value from 0-1023.